# VueJS how to target the current component and createElement within it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to gain relative access to the current component and create a div within it once the components is ready to go.

This is the code for my component, it illustrates that I am trying to get `this` element and create a div within it on the `mounted` lifecycle hook.

```
{
    template: "<div></div>",
    mounted: function(){
        let testElm = this.$el.createElement("DIV")
        testElm.innerHTML = "testing"
    }
}
```

This responds with the following error

```
TypeError: this.$el.createElement is not a function
```

Comment: Updated, it wasn't a direct copy of my code. My actual code has a div in the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things.

[`createElement` is a method of `document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

This is a very non Vue-like way to go about things. If the component has to update the DOM, whatever you are adding in the mounted method will be removed.

You can get the code to work but I do not recommend it. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("test",{
  template: "<div></div>",
  mounted(){
    let test = document.createElement("div")
    test.innerHTML = "this is probably not a good idea"
    this.$el.appendChild(test)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test></test>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks heaps. The reason is that I have an external library which requires an element in order for it to initialise.

Comment: I would probably pass it $el directly, or make a div with a ref in the template and give the library `this.$refs.someDiv`.